# SELECT query taking too long after MySQL upgrade

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just updated my MySQL version to 5.7. A SELECT query that has four INNER-JOINS and that previously took around 3 seconds to execute is now taking so long that I can't even keep track of it. A bit of profiling shows that the 'Send Data' part is taking too long. Can someone tell me what is going wrong? Here's some data. Note that the query is still running at this point in time:

```
    +----------------------+-----------+
    | Status               | Duration  |
    +----------------------+-----------+
    | starting             |  0.001911 |
    | checking permissions |  0.000013 |
    | checking permissions |  0.000003 |
    | checking permissions |  0.000003 |
    | checking permissions |  0.000006 |
    | Opening tables       |  0.000030 |
    | init                 |  0.000406 |
    | System lock          |  0.000018 |
    | optimizing           |  0.000019 |
    | statistics           |  0.000509 |
    | preparing            |  0.000052 |
    | executing            |  0.000004 |
    | Sending data         | 31.881794 |
    | end                  |  0.000021 |
    | query end            |  0.003540 |
    | closing tables       |  0.000032 |
    | freeing items        |  0.000214 |
    | cleaning up          |  0.000028 |
    +----------------------+-----------+
```

Here's the output of EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | movie_data_primary | NULL       | ref  | cinestopId    | cinestopId | 26      | const |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mg                 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  |  387498 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | crw                | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  | 1383452 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cst                | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  | 2184556 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you able to check query execution plan ?

Comment: Haven't done it yet.

Comment: Try to rebuild the index, if it was OK before and then not, it's probably the query builder that try the wrong way...

Comment: Do you mean upgrading the version broke the indices?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like indexing problem when you upgrade the msssql version-
Documentation says-

> If you perform a binary upgrade without dumping and reloading tables, 
>   you cannot upgrade directly from MySQL 4.1 to 5.1 or higher. This
>   occurs due to an incompatible change in the MyISAM table index
>   formatin MySQL 5.0. Upgrade from MySQL 4.1 to 5.0 and repair all
>   MyISAM  tables. Then upgrade from MySQL 5.0 to 5.1 and check and
>   repair your tables.Modifications to the handling of character sets or
>   collations might change the character sort order, which causes the
>   ordering  of entries    in any index that uses an affected character
>   set or    collation to be    incorrect. Such changes result in several
>   possible    problems: Comparison results that differ from previous
>   results
>         Inability to find some index values due to misordered index entries
>         Misordered ORDER BY results
>         Tables that CHECK TABLE reports as being in need of repair

Check for the links-

1)[checking-table-incompatibilities](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/checking-table-incompatibilities.html)

2)[check-table](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/check-table.html)

3)[rebuilding-tables](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/rebuilding-tables.html)

Comment: I just re-built my tables and repaired them as well. But still, the query takes too long :(

Comment: How did you find 'Send Data' particularly takes time?

Comment: I profiled the query. The output is in the question itself.

Comment: Is there index for 'send data' ?

Comment: What is mean is this: Sending data         | 31.881794. I don't have a column named 'Send Data'. When I profile the query, the send data part is taking a lot of time.